# How to get the number of lines in files end of ".c" and ".h" in a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, numbers, line

I know how to get the number of lines in all files end of ".c" in a directory.
I used this command:

```
find nemu/ -name "*.c" |xargs cat|wc -l
```

But how can I get the added number of lines in all files end of ".c" and ".h" in a command?

I mean,switching

```
find nemu/ -name "*.c" |xargs cat|wc -l
```

and

```
find nemu/ -name "*.h" |xargs cat|wc -l
```

to one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wildcard pattern `*.[ch]` to match files ending in either `.c` or `.h`.

```
find nemu/ -name "*.[ch]" |xargs cat|wc -l
```